# Error at installing my app on mobile for testing

Tags: android

my package name is **com.example.project name** but to upload it on google console for publishing it.I change it to **com.ahsan.project name,** now when i am trying to run it on my mobile it is showing me this error....

already have tried to revert back to old changes but it is not working.still getting the same result.

> Run Window

```
Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.example.ethlon
at com.android.server.pm.Settings.getInstallerPackageNameLPr(Settings.java:5051)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstallerPackageName(PackageManagerService.java:27786)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:27792)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:23919)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:993)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:912)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:134)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:28572)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:581)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:481)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3209)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5078)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
Error while Installing APKs
```

Comment: i will refer you to this . if you find it helpful upvote comment for others guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

- this error happen because
- your package name not the same in all project
- search and update your package to be the same

Answer (score 0):

- Most of the time this error came due to **Changes in file location in Project folder**.
- To solve this problem you just have to open whole project again as a new Project.

Steps-

1. **File**-**Export To Zip File** (save as new zip file).
2. **Unzip** the zip file.
3. Go to **Open** and select the location of unzip file.
4. Now try to **run app** on device.